# Right place to ask questions about BitLocker security

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about the countermeasures against [brute-force attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) in [BitLocker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker) and the consequences according to the security of different passphrase lengths.

What would be the correct site to ask such a question?